# Nginx resolving wrong host when upgrading to HTTPS

Tags: nginx

I have 3 *NGINX* hosts, that I only want to serve on HTTPS. Two of them work correctly, however, one of them resolves the wrong host. Here's all of the info

Nginx virtual hosts

```
# cat alpha.domain-a.tld
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name alpha.domain-a.tld;

    return 301 https://alpha.domain-a.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/alpha.domain-a.tld.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/alpha.domain-a.tld.key;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    root /var/www/alpha.domain-a.tld/;
    index index.html;

    server_name alpha.domain-a.tld;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }
}

# cat mike.domain-a.tld
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mike.domain-a.tld;

    return 301 https://mike.domain-a.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/domain-a.tld.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/domain-a.tld.key;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    root /var/www/mike.domain-a.tld/;
    index index.html;

    server_name mike.domain-a.tld;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }
}

# cat juliet.domain-b.tld
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name juliet.dommain-b.tld;

    return 301 https://juliet.domain-b.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/domain-b.tld.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/domain-b.tld.key;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    root /var/www/juliet.domain-b.tld;  
    index index.html;

    server_name juliet.domain-b.tld;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }
}
```

Alpha and mike resolve correctly, however, when i try to access http://juliet, it redirects me to alpha rather than https://juliet, as shown below:

```
# curl -I --resolve alpha.domain-a.tld:80:127.0.0.1 http://alpha.domain-a.tld/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: #OMMITED
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: #OMMITED
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://alpha.domain-a.tld/

# curl -I --resolve mike.domain-a.tld:80:127.0.0.1 http://mike.domain-a.tld/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: #OMMITED
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: #OMMITED
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://mike.domain-a.tld/

# curl -I --resolve juliet.domain-b.tld:80:127.0.0.1 http://juliet.domain-b.tld/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: #OMMITED
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: #OMMITED
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://alpha.domain-a.tld/
```

Could anyone help me find out why juliet is resolving the first alphanumeric host (alpha) rather than juliet?

Comment: Is it perhaps in `PHP`?

Comment: Did you reload the configuration file, or restarted Nginx after making your very last changes on juliet ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it appears that the solution was as simple as changin the domain from juliet.dommain-b.tld to juliet.domain-b.tld (single m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `server_name` of juliet:

```
# cat juliet.domain-b.tld
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name juliet.dommain-b.tld;

    return 301 https://juliet.dommain-b.tld$request_uri;
}
```

`juliet.dommain-b.tld` probably doesn't exists? I think your curl-command is correct (with the correct url) but in your nginx config you wrote the wrong name. Your nginx server doesn't know the domain but the dns request resolves correctly to your server and so your server returns the first entry of your nginx config.